# Looking for an easy Microsoft app for "Task"

Tags: app, microsoft-teams

Can you please point us to the right tool?

We (4 users) need an easy and accessible tool (Microsoft products). Most ideally it's on Microsoft Teams (or Microsoft apps).

Hoping the follwing functions in the tool:

- User (or admin) can quickly create "Task" for each teammate.
- The "Task" as a note can contain some descriptive texts.
- The "Task" can be moved, when it comes to different stages (like "Not Started", "In progress" etc) by easy operations (like drag and drop)

What would the be app to use?

Comment: Did my reply help or do you need something else? If so, be more precise with your question.

Comment: @Destroy666, great recommendations! it took me some time to try them before closing this question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trello](https://trello.com) (very easy to use)/[Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) (more complex) are very popular examples of task management web apps that have Microsoft Teams [integrations](https://www.atlassian.com/partnerships/microsoft).

Comment: thank you for the great advice!